# flutter image so little

Tags: flutter

I want to add my logo but logo doesn't seem.

```
 leading: Image.asset(
            "assets/icons/belha-logo.jpg",
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: 40,
            width: 40,
          ),
```

[That is image of my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzXrE.png)

I tried to give width,height and fit property of asset image but dont work

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? move the image to the center or what?

Comment: the text looks too small

Comment: which text? please explain it in more detail.

So your image doesn't show up do you want to make your image larger?

Comment: I'm talking about the image in the leading and the text below it

Comment: well, you need to show all the code inside the app bar, so I can understand it better. And give a better explanation of what kind of UI (image and text) you want to achieve.

Comment: otherwise people won't understand your goal

Comment: i saw that, but your link doesn't explain anything, it's just an image and text inside the app bar.

Your image and the text below your image are inside an app bar, the height of app bar is fixed, if you want to have more flexibility to set the width and the height, try to use PreferredSize

Answer (score 0):

Add your file path on pubspec.yaml
example:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/my_icon.png
    - assets/background.png
```

if you just added a file, u need to kill your app and re launch it

Comment: the text looks too small  i told you wrong

Answer (score 0):

See the fact that you are using the image in the AppBar makes no effect if you increase the height or width of the image.
What you need to do is:-

1. Either make a custom appbar for your use.
2. Or design the logo in such a way that when it is shrinked to that size it doesn't affect the quality.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just add toolbarHeight and leadingWidth in AppBar according to your requirements and that will do the trick :)

```
AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 200,
          leadingWidth: 160,
          leading: Image.network(
            'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Sample_User_Icon.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: 140,
            width: 140,
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(),
      ),
```